# Deploying two Sharepoint Learning Kit solutions on one sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint, solution, slk

We've installed a sharepoint server at our institute and created to portals one arabic and one english. We installed SLK (using Addsolution, Deploy, etc) and it worked fine. Then we installed the Arabic language pack , hoping we could choose the arabic option on the arabic sites but the language pack is installed in the same manner as the initial English version and overwrites everything, so then we have arabic only.

Now I'm not that technical regarding deploying solutions, but i wanted to know is there away of installing two separate solutions (language wise) on the same server for different language portals?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install  WSS or MOSS?

MOSS is able to work at Multi-language platforms, but wss you can't do this.

As you can see in this picture, MOSS give you the chance to select the WebSite language.

[image]
<sub>(source: [fivenumber.com](http://www.fivenumber.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/3.gif))</sub>

Guilherme Ferreira

http://guilhermeferreira.wordpress.com/